# Separate sub sections in external configuration files

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to store sub sections of my web.config into external config files?

Currently i simply got this:

```
<configuration>
    <archiveConfiguration>
        <company>
            <archives>
                <archive name="DocumentPool" type="JU">
                    <parameter key="ConnectionString" value"......" />
                    <parameter key="ArchiveName" value="DocPool" />
                    ....
                </archive>
                <archive name="Bills" type="SU">
                    <parameter key="ConnectionString" value"......" />
                    <parameter key="ArchiveName" value="Bills" />
                    ....
                </archive>
            </archives>
        </company>
    </archiveConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

Is there any way to just extract the following to an external config file?

```
<archives>
    <archive name="DocumentPool" type="JU">
        <parameter key="ConnectionString" value"......" />
        <parameter key="ArchiveName" value="DocPool" />
        ....
    </archive>
    <archive name="Bills" type="SU">
        <parameter key="ConnectionString" value"......" />
        <parameter key="ArchiveName" value="Bills" />
        ....
    </archive>
</archives>
```

How to reference the external config file to web.config so that the application successfully reads the archives section?
I tried adding configSource to archives by referencing to archives.config, but i was completely ignored by the web application. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: why don't you use xml file instead?

Comment: The application wasn't developed by me, so I can't change it on the fly. This is where I need to use external files instead to keep everything as it is and just changing web.config file only

Comment: configSource is the only way it can be done; however, I don't know what it takes for a custom section to implement it.  It may not be supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom subsections support attribute `configSource`, so you can extract them into an external config, by setting to a custom section an attribute configSource, in your case this 'section' is  element. Put this in `Web.config`:

```
<archives configSource="archives.config" />
```

And in the `archives.config` you'll have

```
<archives>
<archive name="DocumentPool" type="JU">
    <parameter key="ConnectionString" value"......" />
    <parameter key="ArchiveName" value="DocPool" />
    ....
</archive>
<archive name="Bills" type="SU">
    <parameter key="ConnectionString" value"......" />
    <parameter key="ArchiveName" value="Bills" />
    ....
</archive>
```

I assume that you've already created a subclass of ConfigurationSection and then added a custom section handler to Web.config [as in this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. This is not the way I want to go but this seem the correct answer to my initial question. As शेखर suggested, I have to rewrite the whole mechanism to support XML-configuration files. This seem the best to me.